How can I create a sequential numbering system for theorem environments that avoids duplicate numbers and resets for each section?
I'd like the theorems to be displayed consecutively as 2.1, 2.2, and so on for each section. Currently, overlapping numbers appear, such as Proposition 5.3, Remark 5.3. How should I modify this to fix the issue?
I cannot avoid using smfthm. If possible, I would like to use {theo} and {prop}, but I want all the numbers to be distinct.
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} 
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm} 
%\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
% パッケージの追加

\usepackage{float}


\usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}    
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n} 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58} 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}

\newtheoremstyle{uprightstyle}% Name   
  {3pt}% Space above   
  {3pt}% Space below   
  {\normalfont}% Body font   
  {}% Indent amount   
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font   
  {.}% Punctuation after theorem head   
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}% Space after theorem head   
  {}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal`)

\theoremstyle{remark}     

% プリアンブルの最後に以下を追加 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} 
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary} 
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark} 
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} 
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} 
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
    
% カウンターをリセットしない 
\makeatletter 
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section} 
\makeatother

% カスタムの「question」環境を作成して番号を削除（これは変更なし） 
\newtheorem*{unnumberedquestion}{Question}

% オプション：環境の見た目をカスタマイズする場合 
\theoremstyle{plain} % または definition, remark など

\begin{document} 
\section{Math} 
\begin{theo} $x=x$ \end{theo} 
\begin{remark}  This is clear. \end{remark} 
\begin{example} $1=1$ \end{example} 
\begin{prop} $x+x=2x$ \end{prop} 
\begin{remark} This is clear. \end{remark} 
\begin{example} $1+1=2$ \end{example} 
%%%\end{section}
    
\end{document}


A quick hint: To pretty-print the code sections of your query, just highlight with your mouse and click on the {} symbol in the ribbon above the editor window.

This document class name has got to be one of the all-time most unintentionally-hilarious naming choices...

@Mico What do you mean ?

Expand "sm" to "small" and look at the last four letters of the document class's name...

Some suggestions:

Do not load the smfthm package

Do not execute \@addtoreset{theorem}{section} 

Start using the theorem environment names you've actually defined -- e.g., theorem and proposition -- instead of theo and prop (which, I gather, are defined by the smfthm package)



\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} 

\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{url,xspace}%, smfthm} 
%\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{%%%% 'amsmath' is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
            amssymb}
            %%%% 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
% パッケージの追加

\usepackage{float}

%%%%\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%%% don't load packages more than once

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}    
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n} 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58} 
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}

\newtheoremstyle{uprightstyle}% Name   
  {3pt}% Space above   
  {3pt}% Space below   
  {\normalfont}% Body font   
  {}% Indent amount   
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font   
  {.}% Punctuation after theorem head   
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}% Space after theorem head   
  {}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal`)

\theoremstyle{remark}     

% プリアンブルの最後に以下を追加 
 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition} 
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary} 
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark} 
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example} 
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} 
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}
    
% カウンターをリセットしない 
%%%%\makeatletter 
%%%%\@addtoreset{theorem}{section} 
%%%%\makeatother

% カスタムの「question」環境を作成して番号を削除（これは変更なし） 
\newtheorem*{unnumberedquestion}{Question}

% オプション：環境の見た目をカスタマイズする場合 
\theoremstyle{plain} % または definition, remark など
%%%% The preceding instruction has no effect since no
%%%% no \newtheorem directives are associated with it.

\begin{document} 

\section{Math} 

\begin{theorem} $x=x$ \end{theorem} 
\begin{remark}  This is clear. \end{remark} 
\begin{example} $1=1$ \end{example} 
\begin{proposition} $x+x=2x$ \end{proposition} 
\begin{remark} This is clear. \end{remark} 
\begin{example} $1+1=2$ \end{example} 
%%%%\end{section} 
%%%% There is no LaTeX *environment* called "section".
    
\end{document}


Addendum: Just for completeness, here's a list of the theorem-like environments that the smfthm package defines: theo, prop, conj, coro, lemm -- all in the "plain" style; defi -- in the "definition" style; and rema and exem -- both in the "remark" style. (I suppose that one thing these environments have in common is that their names are all four-letter words...) However, as noted in the comments below, use of the smfthm package is not required when using the smfart document class. The user guide of the smflatex bundle  explicitly recommends using the amsthm package to create one's theorem-like environments.

Thank you very much. But I cannot avoid using smfthm. If possible, I would like to use {theo} and {prop}, but I want all the numbers to be distinct.

@BrauerManinobstruction - You're free to load the package; just don't use the environments, such as theo and prop, it defines. Why would you consider using the theo and prop environments, which by construction do not adhere to your preferred numbering system, when you take the time to define theorem and proposition, which do adhere to your system? Put differently, why do you bother to define environments called theorem and proposition if you don't intend to use them?

@BrauerManinobstruction - I've looked up section 8, "The smfthm package", of the user guide of the smf[book,art] document class. The very first two sentences of that section are "This section describes the smfthm package. Its use is not mandatory." Conversely, section 7 of the user guide, "Presentation of theorems", states that "Theorems are typeset thanks to the package amsthm." Happily, your document does employ the amsthm package to set up various theorem-like environments that adhere to your preferred numbering style. Why not use what you've set up so carefully?

Following your advice, I changed all the instances of "theo" to "theorem," and it successfully produced the output I wanted. I had been struggling with this issue for three whole days, so your help was a lifesaver. I'm truly grateful.

@BrauerManinobstruction - You're most welcome! Thanks for letting me know that I was able to help.

The smfthm package already defines what you're trying to reproduce.
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart} 
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{url,smfthm} 
%\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % not with smfart
% パッケージの追加

\usepackage{float}


% \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % not with smfart

\usepackage{hyperref}

\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=Straight Barb},
}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}


\begin{document}

\section{Math}

\begin{theo} $x=x$ \end{theo} 

\begin{rema}  This is clear. \end{rema}

\begin{exem} $1=1$ \end{exem}

\begin{prop} $x+x=2x$ \end{prop}

\begin{rema} This is clear. \end{rema}

\begin{exem} $1+1=2$ \end{exem}

\end{document}


